# R remove parts of a list based on another list of indices

Tags: r, list, indices

I have a list where each element is a vector ("`l1`") and another list where each element contains corresponding indices of `l1` that I want to remove. It's easiest to describe with this example

```
# create some lists in a structure like mine
set.seed(2021)
l1 <- list()
list_indices_to_remove <- list()
for(i in 1:3){
  l1[[i]] <- rbinom(4, 10, .6)
  list_indices_to_remove[[i]] <- sample(1:4, sample(1:2, 1))
}
```

`l1` looks like this

```
[[1]]
[1] 7 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 6 6

[[3]]
[1] 7 6 4 3
```

And for each element I want to remove from the vector those indices that are in `list_indices_to_remove`

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 1 2
```

To put this in words: I want to remove the second and third elements of the vector in `l1[[1]]`, the fourth element in in `l1[[2]]`, ... I could do this in a loop, but I need to do this a lot of times and I'm hoping to find a solution that is quicker.

I have tried a few things, here is one

```
l1[which(l1 %in% list_indices_to_remove)] <- NULL
```

But this does not alter the list. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
Map(function(x, y) x[!seq_along(x) %in% y], l1, list_indices_to_remove)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is effective and fast! I have not used `Map` much in the past, usually `lapply` instead, but this is great.